# Bootstrap - change tab

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I want to link to an item in another bootstrap tab (and change the tab) from an image map link:
This works but from a normal link.
http://jsfiddle.net/k5Lv95L1

I want to do this from an image map:

```
<area shape="rect" href="#target" data-tab="#gallery-panel" coords="295,1109,365,1126"/>
```

But it does not work. Perhaps i need to change the script?

```
$("a[data-tab]").on('click', function() {
    var tab = $(this).attr('data-tab'),
        target = $(this).attr('href');
    $('ul.nav a[href="' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 10);    
});
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Your current code target is "An anchor link with the data-tab attribute".  Have you tried simply changing it to `$("[data-tab]")` as you're no longer associating it to `<a>` but to `<area>` ?

Comment: Thanks, this works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out

```
$("area[data-tab]").on('click', function() {
  var tab = $(this).attr('data-tab'),
    target = $(this).attr('href');
  $('ul.nav area[href="' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
  }, 10);    
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Indeed, this works. I actually implemented Robert C's answer since it seems it works for anchors and areas, but your answer addresses my specific issue.